# Finger tracking using Kinect SDK in C++

Tags: c++, windows, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I want to implement finger tracking using Kinect SDK in C++. I have worked on a lot of hand gestures but I'm stuck at finger tracking. Can you tell me some good libraries or open source projects to get a head start? I am working on Windows 7 64 bit system. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries in c++ that support it out of the box but if you are just looking for a head start or a starting point you might want to look at [This](http://candescentnui.codeplex.com/) or [this](http://frantracerkinectft.codeplex.com/). Its in c# but it should give you a good idea and it does involve finger detection including directional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV along with your Kinect SDK for finger tracking. Here is an inspiring video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xML2S6bvMwI

You can also see this link:
[Finger detection in human hand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893506/finger-detection-in-human-hand)