# Finger detection in human hand

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

**What i am trying to do:**

I am trying to extract the fingers.
I want my code to perform something similar like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGpTE1RkEvQ).
However, aim is to extract the knuckle.

**Environment:**

The person sitting in a typical webcam pc/laptop environment.

**What have i analysed:**

I've read read and understood that 
1. I have to find the contours
2. Need to find convex null and convexityDefects
3. Have to draw contours 
Am i wrong with my understanding?

I have just tried with the code(http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html), but not getting the desired result.

**Question:**
How to extract the fingers in computer vision using opencv?

Ofcourse, i am new to Image Processing.

Comment: When you say "not getting the desired result" what do you mean? Does your program not compile? segfault? run too slowly? not obtain the results you want? what results do you want? Hard to help without looking at your images.

Comment: You are correct with your understanding regarding contours and convexity defects but I'm not sure why you need the convex hull - that will remove the convexity defects that you are looking for.

Comment: You can try this, there is a code available in the about section of the video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCuItHQEgEQ

Comment: Just a curious question, do you have access to Kinect? Cause I did something both similar in Kinect and OpenCV. OpenCV for classifier and the normal image processing stuff, while Kinect, though not an expert in it, I was helping a friend, where he was using kinect to translate sign language. I think Kinect is worth exploring if you have time and access to it.

Comment: @rockinfresh Thanks for your reply.. I don't have access to kinect
and the code should work with only the webcam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code and thesis paper for program from [video (modified version)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_996539&feature=iv&src_vid=mGpTE1RkEvQ&v=th8hUD7Ajg4) in you question is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t22mblcu02xf7dt/yNwsZY1aBW

Comment: The second link is dead, can you please update, thanks!

Comment: It not my project, you can contact author of video for help.